Gauge Anomalies General scenario using Fujikawa Method
I would like to ask a question about Gauge Anomalies and how we can extract them through the Fujikawa method, without using the general triangle diagram as proposed by Weinberg Volume 2 Chapter 22.3.
Firstly, let me revise my understanding of the Fujikawa method in the scenario of the axial symmetry. We have that the action remains invariant under the axial transformation.
\begin{equation}
\psi \mapsto e^{i\theta(x)\gamma^5}\psi=\Delta(x)\psi
\end{equation}
This transformation is indeed a symmetry of the theory in the Dirac Kinetic term in the massless limit, given that $\{\gamma^5,\gamma^{\mu}\}=0$. Then we need to verify how the path integral measure is modified. Towards that end we consider the determinant of the transformation. We take advantage of the fact that a determinant can be expressed as a the exponential of the trace.
\begin{equation}
det|\Delta(x)| = e^{Tr(ln(\Delta(x)))}
\end{equation}
In fact we can express the determinant as a rather ill-defined integral which needs to be regularised. We have,
\begin{equation}
tr(ln(\Delta(x))) = i\int \theta(x)tr[\gamma^5]\delta^{(4)}(0)
\end{equation}
The presence of the delta function and trace over the gamma matrix makes the integral ill-defined. Now, when it comes to emulating this process with respect to standard model which is a Chiral gauge theory, in the sense that it treats left and right chiral parts differently, we have as far as the Hypercharge transformation is concerned.
\begin{equation}
 L_{L}\mapsto e^{i\theta(x)Y}L_L \hspace{1cm} e_r \mapsto e^{\theta(x)Y_{-1}}e_r
\end{equation}
Now, as far as the spinor is concerned, we have that
\begin{equation}
e_L: \psi \mapsto e^{-\frac{i}{2}\theta(x)P_L}\psi \hspace{1cm} e_R: \psi \mapsto e^{-i\theta(x)P_R}\psi
\end{equation}
I used that notation to highlight the different rotations of each chiral part. Of course somebody could perform the following rotation altogether.
\begin{equation}
e:\psi \mapsto e^{-i\theta(x)({\frac{1}{2}P_L+P_R})}
\end{equation}
Now we see that we have $\gamma^5$ matrices which make us fall back into the usual Fujikawa method and, indeed retrieve the anomalous term.
What remains is to generalise with respect to the SU(3)$_c$ and SU(2)$_L$ theories. So we have that under, for instance, the SU(2) left gauge symmetry, the $\gamma^5$ term becomes explicit accounting that it only couples to left-handed particles, so by default, the Gauge transformation is chiral. My question concerns the colour symmetry, which we can extend to any kind of gauge symmetry. So we have that in the Chiral limit, where the mass term becomes un-important, the Gauge symmetry can be applied separately to the kinetic terms corresponding to the left and right-handed chiral parts in the same way we have the U(1)$^5$ flavour-blind symmetry of the kinetic sector of the Standard model. So the actual transformation can be set to be equal to (in the case of the up quark)
\begin{equation}
  u: \psi \mapsto e^{i\theta(x)_aT^aP_L+i\theta(x)_bT^bP_R}\psi
\end{equation}
In that way we can do the same trick as we did with respect to the Hypercharge and to a certain extend the SU(2) left symmetries.
Am I missing something? Is my treatment of a general Gauge Symmetry (like the SU(3) one) correct? Sorry for the long exposition, and thank you in advance.
UPDATE: Probably my question was naive, and the final claim was completely wrong. QCD is vector like, so it does not produce any anomalies. The last equation I put forward should have been
\begin{equation}
  u: \psi \mapsto e^{i\theta(x)_a(P_L+P_R)T^a}\psi = e^{i\theta(x)_aT^a}\psi
\end{equation}
